# Splitting one column into 2 columns - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 pieces of data

```
     Column1
DY04837293530000LFOY
DY9586074510000LOY
```

I am looking for this result

```
 Column1           Column2
DY04837293         530000
DY95860745         10000
```

I need to take the first 10 characters and put them in the first column and then remove the characters on the end and just add the remaining numbers in the middle to column 2.

Can anyone give me any advice on the best way to approach this? thanks

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql

Comment: Did you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/how-do-i-split-a-string-so-i-can-access-item-x

Comment: If you follow the link from @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ I would strongly suggest you run away from that loop based splitter in the accepted answer. Looping is a terrible way to split strings. But in your case you don't need a splitter because your string isn't delimited.

Comment: we do not write code for you at stackoverflow

Comment: but please look at substring()     left()  and right() and usage of variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DECLARE @test VARCHAR(255) = 'DY04837293530000LFOY'

SELECT  @test ori
,       SUBSTRING(@test, 1, 10) first_10
,       SUBSTRING(@test, 11, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', SUBSTRING(@test, 11, LEN(@test))) - 1) last_numbers
```

Results in:

```
+----------------------+------------+--------------+
|         ori          |  first_10  | last_numbers |
+----------------------+------------+--------------+
| DY04837293530000LFOY | DY04837293 |       530000 |
+----------------------+------------+--------------+
```

Comment: you could have let him at least try

Comment: @MichaelEvanchik I know, that's usually my sentiment as well. This time I decided to answer.